# Infinite sequence of trees that are not subgraphs to each other

Tags: graph-theory, trees

This is from a set of exercises and I am stuck to this. Please, have in mind, that I want to understand how it's solved, I am not just looking for a solution.

Define an infinite sequence of trees $T_1, T_2, T_3, ...$ (by drawing the first elements of the sequence), where, for any $i$ and $j$, with $i \neq j$, $T_i$ is not a subgraph of $T_j$. We can see that the set of trees is not well-quasi-ordered to the relation of the "subgraph".

My mind has made it to this stage:
A tree is connected graph, with no cycles.
A subgraph $H$ of $G$, is formed from $G$, by deleting vertices and edges (you may skip an operation (e.g. delete only vertices)).
I thought starting with a tree with four nodes. Let $T_1$ be the tree with edges:
$(1, 2)
(2, 3)
(3, 4)$
and $T_2$:
$(1, 3)
(1, 4)
(2, 4)$
but then what?

Comment: What about two stars of size $42$ joined by a path of length $n$?

Comment: I am really new to this class, so can you please explain? :)

Comment: See [a star](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_(graph_theory)), and [a path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_graph) at Wikipedia.

Comment: I understand the structures, but why you want the size to be 42 (i.e. one inner node and 42 outer ones)?

Comment: Because the number 42 magically makes everything work, you can read more about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life.2C_the_Universe.2C_and_Everything_.2842.29).

Comment: I do not believe in magic, sorry. I mean, in  my eyes, it seems that I can use two stars with six outer nodes, connected by a path of size n and still be ok. I would really like to here back, since I want to learn. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments above by dtldarek, I will solve this assignment like this:

Ti will be two S6 (star graphs that have 6 outer nodes and one internal), joined by a path of length i.